# rails controller with namespace with shorter url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here is my code

```
  namespace :appname do
  resources :docs do
    collection do
      get 'contact'
      get 'how_it_works'
      get 'terms'
      get 'privacy'                  
    end
  end
  end
```

It generates

```
/appname/docs/contact
/appname/docs/how_it_works
/appname/docs/privacy
/appname/docs/terms
```

But how to make them as

```
/docs/contact
/docs/how_it_works
/docs/privacy
/docs/terms
```

my controller code

```
class Appname::DocsController < ApplicationController
  def how_it_works

  end

  def privacy

  end

  def contact

  end


  def terms

  end  
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

defined the routes as follow

```
scope module: 'appname' do
  resources :docs do
    collection do
      get 'contact'
      get 'how_it_works'
      get 'terms'
      get 'privacy'                  
    end
  end
end
```

you can get more info from the rails routing guide in the namespace section. http://guides.ruby-china.org/routing.html

Answer (score 0):

Remove the outer `namespace :appname ... end` block.

Comment: but it conplains DocsController uninitialized constant if i remove the outer block

Comment: Ah, given the namespaced controller, you could just do `scope module: 'appname' do ... end` instead of the namespace block.